# Why Xcode lost code snippets when reopen?

Tags: xcode

Anybody know why My Xcode lost code snippets when I reopen the Xcode?
I try to reinstall and upgrade the Xcode, It's does't work. Thanks!

System: macOS Sierra Version:10.12.2
Xcode: 8.2.1 (8C1002) (version 7 also have this problem).

Comment: I've never had this problem. It may help us to help you if you could provide more details. EDIT: Been using Xcode (although not code snippets) since version 3.

Comment: My problem was that I by accident deleted `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData`

Comment: I accidentally deleted them too... arghhhhh

Answer (score 0):

I solution this problem by myself. I found in /Users/Caohr/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData don't have the CodeSnippets Folder, But have a shortcut of CodeSnippets. And I deleted the shortcut and build new folder of CodeSnippets. It's working!